# Not able to pass json object to python server program

Tags: jquery, python, json, rest, logging

I have an application on python flask and jquery. I face the below problem whenever I try to invoke a logging mechanism on certain events. I haven't found an answer on stackoverflow which could solve this problem

```
POST http://localhost:5000/uploadLog/[object%20Object] 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
```

In frontend.js file:

```
    var eventObj = { 
                               'eventType': 'Type1',
                               'eventDesc': event.target.href
            };
$.post('/uploadLog/'+eventObj, function(response){
            alert("successfully logged");
        })
```

In controller.py:

```
@app.route('/uploadLog/<eventObj>', methods=['POST'])
def uploadLog(eventObj):
    loggerProg.updateLog(eventLogObj)
    return jsonify({'status':'success'})
```

In loggerProg.py:

```
def updateLog(eventObj):
    parsed_obj = json.load(eventObj)
```

I tried to write the eventObj in a file and I got "[object Object]" in the file.

Comment: You can not pass a Json objects in the URL, send it as data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to a) serialize the JavaScript object prior to POSTing it to the server and b) set the `Content-Type` header of the request to `application/json` as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/uploadLog",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(eventObj),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function() {
        alert("Success!");
    }
});
```

Then on the server, parse the request body using Flask's `get_json()` function for convenience:

```
@app.route('/uploadLog', methods=['POST'])
def uploadLog():
    parsed_obj = request.get_json()
```

Comment: Can you run a fiddler trace and make sure the POST is going to the correct url?  It should be going to '/uploadLog'

Comment: it does not work . getting this error - 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Comment: yes. it is going to the correct url - http://localhost:5000/uploadLog . I am checking this in the chrome developer tools . I even tried using json.loads() instead of json.load()

Comment: Please see my updated answer.  I am setting "content type" on the request and am using the convenience method request.get_json() on the server.

Comment: Awesome. It worked like charm! Thanks.  This is very useful method. earlier, request.body was not working. Any idea why it was not working? once you share this info, I will mark your answer immediately

Comment: From what I gather, Flask is a stickler for setting the "content type" header.  That would be my best guess.

Comment: I was also going to suggest running things in "debug" mode next time which might reveal more info. `app.run(debug=True)`